# Extract and store alternate lower 32 bits from AVX register

Tags: vectorization, simd, intrinsics, avx2

I have a __m256i register and I want to extract the 4 lower 32 bit from each 64 bit group, pack them and store them continuosuly to memory. I.e., if the __m256i register contains the 8 32 bit words: { a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7 }, I want to store to memory contiguosly the four words { a0, a2, a4, a6 }

I came up with the following code:

```
void mystore(uint32 *dst, const __m256i& src)
{
      __m256 ps256    = _mm256_castsi256_ps(src);
      __m128 lo128    = _mm256_extractf128_ps(ps256, 0);
      __m128 hi128    = _mm256_extractf128_ps(ps256, 1);
      __m128 pack128  = _mm_shuffle_ps(lo128, hi128, 0 + (2<<2) + (0<<4) + (2<<6));
      __m128i r    = _mm_castps_si128(pack);
     _mm256_storeu_si256( reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(dst), r )
}
```

If I am correct, the cast operations are there just to satisfy the compiler type-checking, but they are in effect equivalent no-op, so the total latency cost is 3 for the shuffle instruction and the 2 extract instructions, plus the cost of the unaligned store.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `_mm256_extractf128_ps(ps256, 0);` is also just a cast.  The low half of every YMM register is accessible as the corresponding XMM register, and fortunately compilers know this and don't punish us for writing extract(v, 0) instead of whatever the right `_mm_cast` intrinsic more directly expresses the optimal asm.  (Similarly, compilers use MOVD when you write `_mm_extract_epi32(v, 0)` instead of an actual PEXTRD).

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try use something like this:

```
const __m256i K_PERM = _mm256_setr_epi32(0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7);

inline void mystore(uint32_t * dst, const __m256i & src)
{
    __m256i permuted = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(src, K_PERM);
    __m128i lo128 = _mm256_extractf128_si256(permuted, 0);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)dst, lo128);
}
```

Comment: Given the permute instruction has latency 3, based on the comments above this seems more expensive than the existing solution. Nonetheless I will give it a try.

Comment: I think that main restriction is a memory bandwidth (for both variants).

Comment: Don't use global `__m256i` constants; compilers init them inefficiently (by copying to the BSS at run-time).  Otherwise yes, one `vpermd` is what you want.  (You could use `_mm256_castsi256_si128` instead of extract, but most compilers optimize away the extract(v, 0). )  Since you only care about the the low 128 of the shuffle result, you could use only a `__m128i` shuffle control so you don't need to load as much constant data.  (`_mm256_castsi128_si256` to use it with a 256-bit shuffle.)